# How to extract the email id from textarea field

Tags: php, jquery, regex, cakephp, tinymce

I am using cakephp. And I have textarea field where users paste data, I using tinymce plugin to format text. I have warned users not to enter telephone number or email address inside the textarea. But, I dont want to take chances.

Is there a way I can extract the telephone number and email from textarea and replace it something like XXXX@gmail.com..

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something off the top of my head for replacing the e-mail address with hidden:

```
$str = "My e-mail is shown@gmail.com Contact me for more details";
$str = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z0-9\._]+)(@[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)/", "hidden\\2", $str);
print($str);
```

The e-mail regex is not the best, but it's something that works for your example. You can get more interesting regexes (emails and phone numbers) at http://www.regexlib.com/ and use them with a simple preg_replace.

Answer (score 1):

You could:
`$string = "blabla@blablabla.com";`

`$parts = explode("@",$string);`

`\\$parts[0] contains the local part`

`\\$parts[1] contains the domain.`

Keep in mind that, (even though it is not usual), the format defined by RFC 822 allows the "@" symbol to appear within quotation marks. This means: "bl@bla"@blablabla.com is *technically* correct.